# Facebook API - post/share activity from my app to users wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating an facebook app for kart racing. I've users registrated with Facebook, with `publish_actions` scope.

This gives me an opportunity to post to his wall his results, until the access token expires (2 hours).

My clients would need to post a message or share a link or share an activity everytime the user finishes the race.

The code I use now is:

```
$config = array(
        'appId' => 'xxxx',
        'secret' => 'xxxxx',
        'allowSignedRequest' => false // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
    );

    $facebook = new Facebook($config);

        if($user_id) {

        // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
        // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
        try {
            $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/'.$user_id.'/feed', 'POST',
                array(
                    'link' => 'www.example.com',
                    'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
                ));
        }
```

Is there other permission I need to get to be able to post somehow to users wall, or share link? How can this be achieved?

Edit: 
Just to be more specific, the kart racing isn't a facebook online game, it's real world kart racing, and I would like to post the racer result to his wall somehow after the end of the race.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending // And please be aware that you should a) _not_ publish stuff automatically when the user is not expecting this, and b) in the way shown here it is a clear violation of Platform Policies, because you are posting a message that the user did not type in themselves. (Instead of regular wall posts, you should look into Open Graph actions if you want to share “results” of any kind.)

Comment: Thanks for information - could you please point me to some tutorial or explanation how actions work and how to share them to users wall? I found the documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/, but don't really understand how that works...

Comment: Well then start with the overview: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/overview